# The best approach to scramble CSS definitions to a human-unreadable state throughout an ASP.NET application

Tags: css, security, scramble, security-by-obscurity

I'm not sure if it will bring anything beyond saving on traffic through the removal of long-worded names, but I would definitely want to hide my system of namings, declarations and their organization.

The thing is that manual Find&Replace is going to take a very long time, and each slight modification could probably require the process to be redone in part or in whole.

Has anyone thought of this problem? Maybe write a macros? Will it be intelligent enough to be able to discover names in a CSS file? Does anything better and simplier exist?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? You can't change the names of the CSS attributes, so at best you're just going to be able to have hard-to-read class/id names. That's still not going to be very hard for someone to decipher.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make it "unreadable", but you can save some space by using things like [the CSS optimizer](http://www.cssoptimiser.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try YUI Compressor:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I don't think I would do it at all, what exatly is to be gained by making it less readable?

But if one had to do it, why not make a custom parser that would convert your "development" names to "production" names and vice versa as needed?

Comment: And how to write such a parser? With the help of VS or something from scratch?

Comment: Depends on what languages you are familar with.  VB.NET or C# would be easy to do a text parser in for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Perl](http://perl.org).  A [simple perl script](http://joseph.randomnetworks.com/archives/2005/08/18/perl-oneliner-recursive-search-and-replace/) can search through all of your files recursively and replace whatever you specify with something else.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS compressor. It will make it really hard to read, but it's not possible to make it completely unreadable. Here's one from [CSS Drive](http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/main/csscompressor/).

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you can make the names shorter or less meaningful, but to reach a *human-unreadable state* is essentially not possible.

No matter how you rename or distort the css, it still has to have proper atributes and the html has to reference the named classes and/or ids.
Additionally tools like firebug will unfailingly point users to the css being used which I assume will defeat your intent.

It also defeats the purpose of using semantically meaningful tags in your html.